# IIS returns 404 error by my node.js server

Tags: node.js, express, iis

I'm now developing a website through Node JS and IIS.
In internal IP, I'm trying to make sure that sites that operate without problems can be accessed from external IP.
I already have an IP that I have, so I want to make it accessible by adding an application within that site.
On localhost, however, 404 errors occur when a file that is connected is added to an application on an external site.
I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it

I modified the index.js file to make sure it works. But even this file has 404 error.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const { user } = require('./dbconfig');
const app = express() ;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;
const pool = require('./sql');
const path = require('path');


app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'/views'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'uploads')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/views')))


app.get('/',async(req,res) =>{
res.send('just do it');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server on = http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
            <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <iisnode watchedFiles=".js;node_modules\*;routes\*.js;views\*.jade" nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="SendToNode" enabled="true">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" />
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ejs" mimeType="text/html" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

this is my IIS list. TS_AS application returns 404 error

[image]

i add my applicationHost.config  tag

```
        <sites>
            <site name="Default Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
                </application>
                <application path="/--------" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\--------" />
                </application>
                <application path="/TS_AS" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TS_AS" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <site name="test" id="3" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TS_AS" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
        </sites>
```

I'm a noob programmer, so I'm sorry that I can't explain the problem well

When this setting is deployed to the localhost site(test), the screen is displayed without any problems.

[image]

Comment: People will be more interested in the `<sites>` tag inside `applicationHost.config` than a screen shot of IIS Manager.

Comment: Try using FRT to view details about the 404 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by my self. thank you for comment to my question

the probelm is Get request address

```
app.get('/TS_AS/',async(req,res) =>{
res.send('just do it');
});
```

i have to add my application directory infront of GET adress

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.